# structure declaration question

Tags: c, data-structures

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/8139too.c#L498
On above link
What I am not getting is 
the structure

```
static const struct {
        const char *name;
        u32 version; /* from RTL8139C/RTL8139D docs */
        u32 flags;
} rtl_chip_info[] = {
        { "RTL-8139",
          HW_REVID(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
          HasHltClk,
        },
```

gets expanded to

```
static const struct {
        const char *name;
        u32 version; /* from RTL8139C/RTL8139D docs */
        u32 flags;
} rtl_chip_info[] = {
        { "RTL-8139",
**(b30, b29, b28, b27, b26, b23, b22)
        (b30<<30 | b29<<29 | b28<<28 | b27<<27 | b26<<26 | b23<<23 | b22<<22)
(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),**
          HasHltClk,
        },
```

I do not understand above type (2nd) of structure declaration.

Comment: How did you generate the 2nd <code> above? The HW_REVID macro just packs the bits you pass into a 4-byte int. Also note that everything after the first } is not part of the structure definition, but is initializing some instances of the structure.

Comment: Your "gets expanded to" code is incorrect. Where did you get it? Macro `HW_REVID` does not get expanded to anything like that. Please, post *real* expanded code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(b30, b29, b28, b27, b26, b23, b22)` doesn't actually make it into the code -- they're parameters for the `HW_REVID` macro. In other words,

```
HW_REVID(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
```

turns into

```
(1<<30 | 0<<29 | 0<<28 | 0<<27 | 0<<26 | 0<<23 | 0<<22)
```

because the `b30` etc. are replaced (note by replaced I mean literally copy and pasted) by the `1, 0,` etc. So when all is said and done it looks like:

```
static const struct {
    const char *name;
    u32 version; /* from RTL8139C/RTL8139D docs */
    u32 flags;
} rtl_chip_info[] = {
    { "RTL-8139",
      (1<<30 | 0<<29 | 0<<28 | 0<<27 | 0<<26 | 0<<23 | 0<<22), /* originally HW_REVID(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), */
      HasHltClk,
    }
```

I don't know what compiler you're using, but if you're using gcc for example, you can pass the `-E` switch to do only the preprocessing (replacing #defines and macros and so forth) so you can see exactly the code it is compiling looks like.

Comment: Thanks all I was really confused over that macro and I had forgotten about the ending brace ) so I was not able to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

HW_REVID is simply a macro for settings 1's in various bit positions 30 through 22.  It is defined as:

```
#define HW_REVID(b30, b29, b28, b27, b26, b23, b22) \
        (b30<<30 | b29<<29 | b28<<28 | b27<<27 | b26<<26 | b23<<23 | b22<<22)
```

When called as HW_REVID(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) it gets expanded as:

```
    (1<<30 | 0<<29 | 0<<28 | 0<<27 | 0<<26 | 0<<23 | 0<<22)
```

which shifts a 1 30 places left (into bit 30) initializing the 32-bit version field to 0x40000000.